# CSRF protection not working in Laravel + Sanctum rest api

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-sanctum

I am creating authorization in SPA,

On the server - Laravel + sanctum

On the client - Vue + Axios

I want to make protection against CSRF, for this I installed the Sanctum package

in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file added Middleware

```
'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

in `routes/api.php` file

created route `Route::post ('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);`

in the controller I added a simple validate with registration

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    
    $request->validate([
        'name'     => 'required|string',
        'email'    => 'required|email:rfc,dns|string|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed',
    ]);
    
    $user = User::create([
        'name'     => $request->name,
        'email'    => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);
    
}
```

After I submit the form, the data is seamlessly added to the database and User created.

Although Sanctum suggests that in addition I have to send cookies with `XSRF-TOKEN`. Otherwise, an error should be returned to me that there is no CSRF token with http status 419.

But there is no error and data is added

There are no saved cookies in the browser, I checked, cleaned, opened in incognito, tried sending requests through Postman

I want to see this error, but I am not getting it

Tell me what is missing?

Comment: have you tried `config:clear` and `cache:clear`?

Comment: yes,
`php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` and restart local server

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#csrf-protection `To authenticate your SPA, your SPA's "login" page should first make a request to the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint to initialize CSRF protection for the application`, so initialize at the time of loading of your login page

Comment: and it only needs to be done once per session

Comment: Yes, I read that.
And if I have not received the token, then Laravel must reject my request.
But it does not reject it, and the data is added to the database.

Otherwise, if everyone can make the request without receiving cookies, then the meaning of the protection CSRF is lost.

Comment: CSRF not working with api by design - it's for web pages(e.g. web.php).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I forgot to add to axios

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and in `cors.php`

```
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

after adding these settings, everything worked